# Javascript How To Evaluate On Number or Specific String

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I need to evaluate a form submission to either be 
"TBD" or a number > 0 . Is there a way to do that that I'm not seeing.. here is what I have so far:

```
<script language="Javascript">
function validateForm(){
//Declare Variables
var aa=document.forms["form"]["irnumber"].value;
if (aa =='TBD'){
return true;
}else if (parseInt(aa) < 1 || aa==null || aa=="") {
    alert("IR Must Be A Number Or \"TBD\" ");
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you cannon that logic was eluding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (parseInt(aa) > 0 || aa === "TBD") {
    return true;
} else {
    alert("IR Must Be A Number Or \"TBD\" ");
    return false;
}
```

or

```
if (/^((TBD)|(0*[1-9]+[0-9]*))$/i.test(aa)) {
    return true;
} else {
    alert("IR Must Be A Number Or \"TBD\" ");
    return false;
}
```